# How to add images to the histogram using ggpattern?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to add images to a histogram using ggpattern but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

image_paths <- c("img1.png", "20190530153216.png", "download.png", "dstack2.png", "Dstack091.png", "Rodząca_dafnia.png")

# Sample dataframe with values
df <- data.frame(
  example_column = rnorm(32)  # Replace with your actual data
)

# Create a histogram with images as fill patterns


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = example_column)) +
  geom_histogram_pattern(pattern = "image", aes(pattern_filename = image_paths),
                         pattern_type = "squish") +
  scale_pattern_filename_identity() +
  labs(x = "Residual Value", y = "Count") +
  theme_minimal()

# Display the histogram
print(p)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error in `geom_histogram_pattern()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `pattern_filename`
```

I've tried to add `scale_pattern_filename_manual()` but that didn't work either:

```
img1 <- system.file("img", "img1.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")
img2 <- system.file("img", "20190530153216.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")
img3 <- system.file("img", "download.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")
img4 <- system.file("img", "dstack2.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")
img5 <- system.file("img", "Dstack091.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")
img6 <- system.file("img", "Rodząca_dafnia.jpg"   , package="ggpattern")

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = example_column)) +
  geom_histogram_pattern(pattern = "image",
                         pattern_type = "squish", bins = 6) +
  scale_pattern_filename_manual(values = c(`1` = img1, `2` = img2, `3` = img3, `4` = img4 , `5` =img5 , `6`=img6)) +
  labs(x = "Residual Value", y = "Count") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: I think you need `scale_pattern_filename_manual`, see https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/patterns-image.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461483/how-to-add-images-to-each-bar-of-the-histogram-in-r/77461931#77461931 Where are you specifying the pattern file name in this data? You have `aes(pattern_filename = image_paths)` but `image_paths` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: No that one is for bar charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by Allan Cameron in his answer on your former question you have to map on `pattern_filename`. Otherwise `scale_pattern_filename_xxx` will have no effect. However, in case of `geom_histogram` that is a bit special. Basically we need to map the bin index on `pattern_filename` which could be achieved using `after_stat()`. Second, of course do you need to pass a vector of valid image file paths (which e.g. `system.file("img", "Rodząca_dafnia.jpg", package="ggpattern")` is not) to the `values=` argument of `scale_pattern_filename_manual` . In the code below I simply used the R logo.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

set.seed(123)

ggplot(df, aes(x = example_column)) +
  geom_histogram_pattern(
    aes(
      pattern_filename = after_stat(
        as.character(seq_along(x))
      )
    ),
    pattern = "image",
    pattern_type = "squish",
    bins = 6
  ) +
  scale_pattern_filename_manual(
    values = rep("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", 6),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  labs(x = "Residual Value", y = "Count") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]